# a hard problem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Please give me some ideas! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should include some of your attempts or ideas..

Comment: furthermore, it is not hard. try to apply the definitions first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $A$ satisfies $A(u_i) = \mu_i v_i$ when $(u_i)$ and $(v_i)$ are orthonormal bases. If we define $S$ by $S(u_i) = v_i$ and $D(v_i) = \mu_i v_i$ then $S$ is orthogonal and we have $A = DS$. Hence, $\det(A) = \det(DS) = \det(D)\det(S) = \pm \prod_{i=1}^n \mu_i$. The sign is determinate by the relative orientation of the bases $(u_i)$ and $(v_i)$ (in other words, whether the map $S$ making one basis to the other is orientation preserving [and then $\det(S) = 1$] or orientation reversing [and then $\det(S) = -1$]).